# CSS styled buttons

Tags: html, css

I have come across some CSS for styled buttons which I am using to great effect.  However the code I have creates a self expanding width button according to the button text.

I want to put two buttons on top of each other and have them have exactly the same width regardless of the button text.

Can anyone tell me how I might tweak my existing CSS to allow for this?

```css
/*-- MY CSS READ MORE BUTTON --*/

a.btn,
.btn,
.btn:focus,
input[type="submit"],
a.more-link {
  padding: 13px 30px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #ffffff;
  filter: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
a,
a.btn,
.btn,
.btn:focus,
input[type="submit"],
.btn:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
{
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease, background 0.6s ease, border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: color 0.2s ease, background 0.6s ease, border-color 0.2s ease;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
/*-- EDIT HERE FOR COLOUR CHANGE ON HOVER --*/

.btn:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
a.more-link:hover {
  background: #7acfd6;
  border-color: #cccccc;
  color: #fff;
}
/*-- EDIT HERE FOR ACTIVE BUTTON COLOUR --*/

.btn:active,
.btn-primary,
.btn-primary:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #000000;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:active {
  background: #000000;
}
.btn.alt {
  background: #9BA78A;
  border-color: #9BA78A;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.btn.alt:hover {
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;"><a class="btn" href="#">Learn more</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Add width to the element.

Comment: You need to atleast tell us what have you tried ? If you don't want the button to expand then why not give a **`max-width`/`width` to the buttons** ?

Comment: You could change `display: inline-block` to `block`

Comment: Just so you know, there are a LOT of unneeded CSS in that declaration. Basically, that CSS could be shortened to about half the size for the example provided.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the buttons block elements by giving them a CSS rule of "display: block". Then you can give them a fixed width like 200px using "width: 200px". See code below for a working example.

```css
/*-- MY CSS READ MORE BUTTON --*/

a.btn,
.btn,
.btn:focus,
input[type="submit"],
a.more-link {
  padding: 13px 30px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #ffffff;
  filter: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
a,
a.btn,
.btn,
.btn:focus,
input[type="submit"],
.btn:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
{
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease, background 0.6s ease, border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: color 0.2s ease, background 0.6s ease, border-color 0.2s ease;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
/*-- EDIT HERE FOR COLOUR CHANGE ON HOVER --*/

.btn:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
a.more-link:hover {
  background: #7acfd6;
  border-color: #cccccc;
  color: #fff;
}
/*-- EDIT HERE FOR ACTIVE BUTTON COLOUR --*/

.btn:active,
.btn-primary,
.btn-primary:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #000000;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:active {
  background: #000000;
}
.btn.alt {
  background: #9BA78A;
  border-color: #9BA78A;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.btn.alt:hover {
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;"><a class="btn" href="#">Learn more</a>
</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><a class="btn" href="#">Click here</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**A Simple Tweak for your Issue.** . just added `min-width:130px` to `.btn`

```css
/*-- MY CSS READ MORE BUTTON --*/

a.btn,
.btn,
.btn:focus,
input[type="submit"],
a.more-link {
  padding: 13px 30px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #ffffff;
  filter: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
a,
a.btn,
.btn,
.btn:focus,
input[type="submit"],
.btn:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
{
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease, background 0.6s ease, border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: color 0.2s ease, background 0.6s ease, border-color 0.2s ease;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  min-width:130px
}
/*-- EDIT HERE FOR COLOUR CHANGE ON HOVER --*/

.btn:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
a.more-link:hover {
  background: #7acfd6;
  border-color: #cccccc;
  color: #fff;
}
/*-- EDIT HERE FOR ACTIVE BUTTON COLOUR --*/

.btn:active,
.btn-primary,
.btn-primary:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #000000;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:active {
  background: #000000;
}
.btn.alt {
  background: #9BA78A;
  border-color: #9BA78A;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.btn.alt:hover {
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;"><a class="btn" href="#">Learn more</a>
</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><a class="btn" href="#">Learn</a>
</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><a class="btn" href="#">More More More</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion:

- Make the parent `p` element display `inline-block`

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
}
.btn {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 2px 0;
}
/*-- MY CSS READ MORE BUTTON --*/

a.btn,
.btn,
.btn:focus,
input[type="submit"],
a.more-link {
  padding: 13px 30px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #ffffff;
  filter: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
a,
a.btn,
.btn,
.btn:focus,
input[type="submit"],
.btn:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
{
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease, background 0.6s ease, border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: color 0.2s ease, background 0.6s ease, border-color 0.2s ease;
}
.btn {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
/*-- EDIT HERE FOR COLOUR CHANGE ON HOVER --*/

.btn:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
a.more-link:hover {
  background: #7acfd6;
  border-color: #cccccc;
  color: #fff;
}
/*-- EDIT HERE FOR ACTIVE BUTTON COLOUR --*/

.btn:active,
.btn-primary,
.btn-primary:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #000000;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:active {
  background: #000000;
}
.btn.alt {
  background: #9BA78A;
  border-color: #9BA78A;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.btn.alt:hover {
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;">
  <a class="btn" href="#">Learn more</a>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Learn more and more</a>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Learn more and more and more</a>
</p>

<hr>

<p style="text-align: center;">
  <a class="btn" href="#">Learn more</a>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Learn more and more</a>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Learn more and more and more and more again</a>
</p>
```